# aws ecs autoscaling instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

Currently I am struggling with AWS auto scaling.

Do I need to create instance Auto Scaling Group in parallel to ECS Service Auto Scaling to provision necessary resources for services/tasks, or it is managed automatically by the latter one?

edit:
I am using api/cloudformation only, no web interface.

Comment: It should be handled by the Auto Scaling Group.

Comment: From the docs Your Amazon ECS service can optionally be configured to use Service Auto Scaling to adjust its desired count up or down in response to CloudWatch alarms.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html

Comment: Thank you @Oscar, I certainly missed that point, updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECS service scaling and And EC2 instance scaling are independent entities. EC2 instance scaling is not handled if you configure ECS service scaling. It is required(Mandotory) to configure  EC2 Instance scaling and maintain enough resources in the cluster  if you are opting ECS Service scaling, otherwise ECS service fails to place new Tasks during service scaling activities. In general, it is recommended to scale EC2 Instances based on CPUReservation and MemoryReservation cloudwatch alarms.

EC2 Container Instance scaling tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_alarm_autoscaling.html